# Djnago send mail not working, also not showing any error

Tags: python, django

Settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'testing.email2908@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'testing.email2908@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'testing.email2908@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAILL_USE_TLS = True
```

views.py

```
print('Helloo')
send_mail(
    'Testing',
    'Hi',
    'testing.email2908@gmail.com',
    ['xyz@gmail.com'], #my personal gmail id
    fail_silently=False,
)
print('Hiiii')
```

When i run this code, only `Helloo` is getting printed, I've imported send_mail as well,tried using smtplib as well but that was giving smpt auth extension error so i'm trying send_mail method but it also doesn't seem to work, don't know what is the exact issue.

Comment: What is your `EMAIL_BACKEND` set to in your settings.py?

Comment: `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` add this and this one has typo`EMAILL` in case you copied contect from settings `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`

Comment: there's no such thing as EMAIL_BACKEND, in my settings.py @AshSmith88

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'emailId'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to set Following configuration in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xyz.gmail.com' # sender's email-id
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xyz' # password associated with above email-id
```

I think you forgot EMAIL_BACKEND.

To send mail add following code

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

subject = 'email subject'
message = 'Hi , Thank you for your help.'
email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
recipient_list = [user.email, ] # email to send
send_mail( subject, message, email_from, recipient_list )
```

If you are using gmail for sending mails then you need to turn on `Less Secure App Access`. The option is present in `Manage Your Account` in gmail.

I hope it will help you.